# Creating video from audio and resized image using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

Im trying to create an mp4 video from an mp3 and an image with ffmpeg. The video should be the size of 640x360 with black background and the image should be resized to fit in this dimensions and centred in the middle. The video's length must match the mp3's length.

Its basically a video creation for youtube from a song and an artwork.

For now i was able to achieve this with 3 steps:

1. resize image:

`-i %image% -vf scale='if(gt(a,4/3),640,-1)':'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,360)' %resized_image%`

2. create a music video with black background:

`-f lavfi -i color=s=640x360 -i %audio_file% -c:v libx264 -s:v 640x360 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 320k -shortest -pix_fmt yuv420p %video%`

3. put the resized image centred in the video:

`-i %video% -i %resized_image% -filter_complex "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" -codec:a copy %final_video%`

Is it possible to achieve all this with one ffmpeg command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single command would be

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i image -i audio
-vf scale='if(gt(a,4/3),640,-1)':'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,360)',pad=640:360:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,format=yuv420p
-c:v libx264 -c:a aac -b:a 320k -strict -2 -shortest final.mp4
```